# Default types of constants

Tags: c, c99

When I write:

```
if ((1/3) > 0) ...
```

Will I need to cast one of the operands to (float) to make this condition true? Or what is the default variable-type C is using?

And if I would write:

```
if ((1.0/3) > 0) ...
```

Has the situation now changed, because the compiler notices one of the operands has to be float?

Comment: Why are you comparing floats anyways?

Comment: Sufficiently small integer literals have type `int`, floating point literals have type `double`.

Comment: @AlokSave What do you mean?

Comment: @melpomene So the second example (1.0/3) would result in TRUE because 1.0 is a float literal?

Comment: `1.0` is not a float literal, it's a double literal.

Comment: `1.0` is a floating-point literal. Its type is `double`, its value is `1` :)

Comment: Strictly, there are no variables in the code fragments in the question; everything is a literal.  In C89, the 'default type' for a variable was `int`, so you could write things like `static i = 42;` and `i` was an `int`.  In C99, that 'implicit int' rule was removed (though compilers typically still allow it, usually with a warning; a warning is mandatory in C99 mode).

Comment: This topic is covered in just about every C book out there, or very well should be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In absence of suffixes, sufficiently small numbers have `int` or `double` types

```
a = 42; /* 42 has type int */
b = 42.0; /* 42.0 has type double */
```

You can use suffixes to specify the type of the literal

```
c = 42U; /* unsigned int */
d = 42.0f; /* float */
e = 42.0L; /* long double */
f = 42ULL; /* unsigned long long (in C99; C89 didn't have long long) */
```

Answer (score 5):

> Will I need to cast one of the operands to (float) to make this
>   condition true?

Yes, because integral literals are of type `int` and a division between two `int` types returns also an `int`, meaning that the fraction is omitted.

> Has the situation now changed, because the compiler notices one of 
>   the operands has to be float?

Yes, because one of the operands of the division is now a `double` and therefore the division returns a `double` to maintain precision. (`float` literals are followed by an `f`, as in `1.0f`, but this doesn't matter much regarding your question.)

Comment: `1.0` is not `float`, it's `double`. `float` literals have an `f` suffix, like this: `1.0f`.

Answer (score 1):

"1", "3", "0" are all integers.
while "1.0" is a double.
what's different between the to situations is that double/integer is a double while integer/integer is an integer.